# React native iOS unable to autolink in yarn workspaces

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-cli

I created a project with react native 0.60.4 in a monorepo (using yarn workspaces). The project has de following structure:

```
project
  |
  |- node_modules
  |- packages
     |-react-native-app
       |- ios
       |- android
       |- src
```

I followed the react native docs (https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md) on how to configure autolinking with custom roots, so I changed the paths in my Podfile to:

```
require_relative '../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

use_native_modules!("../../..")
```

The problem is that when I run `pod install` it install only the react-native default dependencies and doesn't identify any 3rd party package added to the app.

Is the podfile configuration right? Should I run any other command to make it work?